# Keycloak how to search users by role AND username/email/other attributes with pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

In my application I have users with roles admin, manager, and applicant

I need to add a search mechanism that searches users of 1 specific role by username/firstname/lastname/email/etc. Like I want to have separate a search page for applicants, separate search page for managers/admins.

The following method searches users with some username/firstname/lastname/email with pagination. But I can't filter by role here.

```
List<UserRepresentation> users = realmResource.users().search(
                request.getUserName(),
                request.getFirstName(),
                request.getLastName(),
                request.getEmail(),
                page * size,
                size);
```

This function gets me users of given role but I can't filter them by other parameters while preserving pagination:

```
List<UserRepresentation> usersByRole = realmResource
                .roles()
                .get(request.getRole())
                .getUserMembers(page * size, size);
```

Is there a way to search both by user role and other user attributes?